# MySQL PDO Multi Select

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When i use this code , i got this error :

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'rules_id.rules' in 'where clause'

I really don't know how to create something like this
In my Database i have :

Tables : rules , users

Columns : 
(rules) => rules_id , allias_name , edit , delete 
(users) => users_id , username , password , rules_id

*I want to create users access rules

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "demo";

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users where rules_id.rules = rules_id.users");
 while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){   
  echo $row["users_id"];
 }
  
  
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: You probably want to join the rules table onto the users table. The proper SQL syntax is `tablename.columnname`. `SELECT
    *
FROM users
JOIN rules t2 ON users.rules_id = rules.rules_id
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at MySQL document about join. In a relational database such as MySQL, MSSQL or Postgres, in order to retrieve data from several related tables at the same time, a join is required. Basically if you want to query rules data for all users, your query should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM users u
JOIN rules r ON u.rules_id = r.rules_id;
```

Links for documents: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp